# Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode while using Itextsharp 5.5.1.0

Tags: c#, dll, itext, sql-session-state

I Got below error while using session state SQL server with itextsharpt dll version 5.5.1.0. I am using asp.net 4.0 web application.

**Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.**

I am using below configuration for session state

cookieless="AutoDetect" cookieName="MYCookie" mode="SQLServer" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false"

How can we Serialize third party dll like itextsharp.

Comment: Which iTextSharp objects do you want to serialize? There are a number of iTextSharp classes for which serialization does not make sense.

Comment: PdfSignatureAppearance objSign = (PdfSignatureAppearance)HttpContext.Current.Session["sap"];                                             above one is working fine with inproc session mode. but it's give an error as mentioned while using sql server session state.

Comment: A `PdfSignatureAppearance` is depending on a `PdfStamper`, and serializing a stamper does not make sense as it depends on an output `Stream`.

Comment: I would say that the serialization is the PDF itself.

Comment: Depending on the state of the signature creation process, that may be possible.